# Leaflet VectorGrid - circle markers cut off at border in custom implementation

Tags: leaflet, clip, vector-tiles

I am extending a custom class from [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) in an effort to optimize rendering high-volume data on a leaflet map, through our api.  My chosen tactic is to create a grid, where each tile is responsible for fetching the data within its bounds, and rendering that data to the screen using a leaflet vectorgrid.  In order to do this, I extend from L.VectorGrid, and institute a custom data-getting function with `_getVectorTilePromise`:

```js
export const StationGridLayer = L.VectorGrid.extend({
  _getVectorTilePromise: async function (
    this: L.StationGridLayer,
    coords: TileCoord
  ) {
    const { x, y, z } = coords;

    // Call to get locations from api based on coords for this tile:
    const geojson = await fetchTile(tilecoordToBounds(tilename(coords)));

    // Create geojsonvt from the geojson
    const vt = geojsonvt(geojson, this.options);

    const tile = vt.getTile(z, x, y);
    const tileLayers: { [key: string]: any } = {};

    if (tile) {
      const vectorTileLayer = {
        features: tile.features.map((feature) => ({
          geometry: feature.geometry,
          properties: feature.tags,
          type: feature.type
        })),
        extent: this.options.extent,
        length: tile.features.length
      };

      tileLayers["pods"] = vectorTileLayer;
    }

    return { layers: tileLayers, coords };
  }
});
```

This is working nicely.  For a working example, see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pe-performance-vt-gridlayer-my585b?file=/src/StationGridLayer.ts). (The sandbox has alot more code to help in cacheing any previously fetched data, but the core concept is the same.)

Locations are rendered to the screen as L.CircleMarkers.  But any marker close to the edge of the tile is cut off, like this:

[image]

This is a well discussed issue, as you can see in the [repo's issues list](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues?q=clip).  Most of the discussions there refer to digging into the options used by [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt), which is used under the hood of leaflet.vectorgrid - namely the `buffer` property.  Supposedly that is supposed to help in including features that are just outside the edges of a single canvas tile.  But for me, no matter what I set the `buffer` to, it does not solve my issue.

```js
const stations = new L.StationGridLayer({
  // this gets passed to geojsonvt, but changing its value
  // makes no difference at all
  buffer: 100, 
  extent: 4096,
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  // ...other options
});
```

However, I do know that this issue is *solvable* right within the code of Leaflet.Vectorgrid.

Another approach is to call for all the data in the bounds of the map, and then feed that to L.VectorGrid.Slicer.  But this is less performant from a api perspective (one big call, vs many smaller, parallel calls).  If I take this approach, there is no issue with tile boundaries:

[image]

[Here is a sandbox demonstrating this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pe-performance-vt-testing-slicer-jb0w2j?file=/src/index.ts:281-373).  Click the "Fetch Manually" button - data is fetched for the total bounds of the map, then fed to `L.VectorGrid.Slicer`.  `L.VectorGrid.Slicer` successfully slices up the tiles, without ugly clipping at the tiles' edges.  I have dug into the source code for [`L.VectorGrid.Slicer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/src/Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer.js), as well as the [`slicerWebWorker.js`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/src/slicerWebWorker.js) file that supports it.  I can't see anywhere in there what it is doing differently than what I am doing.  The use of `geojsonvt` and `_getVectorTilePromise` are very similar - their code waits for a web worker to return GeoJSON, while mine waits for the api to return it.

What am I doing differently that is resulting in the edges being clipped?  How can I solve this edge clipping issue in the same way that L.VectorGrid.Slicer does?

Comment: First idea that comes to mind is to create a certain buffer around a tile and render also everything that falls within this buffer.

Comment: @TomazicM right exactly, the question is how?  It seems that there is already that `buffer` property within geojsonvt, which defaults to 64.  I believe that is what is being used in the `.Slicer` class above, but I can't tell why its not having an affect in my code.  I considered creating my own buffer by having the tiles be, say, 256 + 5 + 5 px by 256 + 5 + 5 px, then have them overlap with each other 10 px, but I was struggling to make that happen, as placement of the tiles on the screen is a bit complex, and it seems like the solution is already hidden inside of the .Slicer code

Comment: Where do you apply this `buffer` property for getting GeoJSON data for tile in your example https://codesandbox.io/s/pe-performance-vt-gridlayer-my585b?file=/src/index.ts?

Comment: @TomazicM good point, I realize I had removed it from the sandbox because it was making no difference.  I added it back into the sandbox, and edited my question as well to show where I apply it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that solution is quite simple. I didn't go into research of how `L.VectorGrid` uses `buffer` option, just simply extended bounds for which GeoJSON data is retrieved for tile by 2% and it seems to work. Measure of bounds extension is of course something to be experimented with.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
if (!geojson) {
 const tileBounds = tilecoordToBounds(tilename(coords)).pad(0.02);
 const response = await fetchTile(tileBounds);
 .
 .
 .
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this is working.  I think the issue is that if you don't include the data point that is just outside of the edge of a tile, it doesn't know to draw the remainder of the symbol that was being cut off.  Thank you!